# Dependency Property With Windows Workflow

Tags: workflow

I have a situation where I have a workflow that uses custom activities within a activity library.  The workflow uses the custom activities that moves from custom activity 1 to custom activity 2.  In custom activity 1 I create a dependency property that passes in my object (say a Widget) with custom properties.  Inside the activity it updates the properties on the Widget (i.e. sets Widget.Name = "New Name").  Inside custom activity 2 I would like to update the same dependent property to update additional properties on the Widget (i.e. set Widget.Title = "New Title").

My question is if I register the Dependency Property in Custom Activity 1 how do I use the dependency property in custom activity 2?  If I try and register the property in the second activity I get a build error saying "A property with the same name already exists".  The other idea I had was instead of registering the dependency property I tried to use DepenedncyProperty.FromName but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: I can't deobfuscate your first paragraph. The second sounds like you're having trouble getting/using the DependencyProperty defined on one activity from another. Show us your code. It should look something like this: 

DependencyProperty tp = DependencyProperty.FromName("Title", activity.GetType());